# What command made this change?

Tags: vim, command, shortcut

[image: before]

[image: after]

I pushed a key and accidently the text is arraged. I like this way but I cannot know what key I pressed. These screens are captured with help of undo command('u' key).

Surely I tried 'q:' or 'history', but those command only shows the commands that started with colon(:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you've formatted the single long compiler command with `gqq` (or `gql`, or `Ql` if you have that mapping).

The `gq` command reformats lines; by default, that means inserting hard line breaks at the screen width or `'textwidth'`; indeed, this makes the output easier to read.

#### Alternative

Your initial screenshot shows that you have soft wrapping enabled (`:set wrap`); with an additional `:set linebreak`, the wrapping would only occur on certain characters, not on the last fitting character, giving a similar effect as the reformatting, but without actually changing the text.

Answer (score 1):

You probably used line wrapping
gq

use it in combination with numbers as you would use 'y' or 'd' commands
for wrapping 4 lines: gq4gq OR 4gqgq
for wrapping from cursor to the end: gqG
etc

see more here:
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatic_word_wrapping